# HttpClient GET request fails, POST Succeeds

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, restsharp

In a Xamarin application (backed by ASP.NET WebApi), I'm having trouble getting [all of] my `GET` requests to succeed -- they return 404.  In fact, when watching network traffic in Fiddler, I don't even see the request happen.

Here is [basically] what I'm doing:

```
public async Task<bool> ValidateSponsor(string attendeeId, string sponsorId)
{
    string address = String.Format("{0}/Sponsors/?attendeeId={1}&sponsorId={2}", BASE_URI, attendeeId, sponsorId);

    var response = await client.GetAsync(address);
    var content = response.content;

    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        throw new HttpRequestException("Check your network connection and try again.");

    string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return Convert.ToBoolean(result);
}
```

If I copy out the `address` variable and paste it into a browser, it succeeds.  `POST` requests (to different methods, of course) succeed.  I've also tried using the PCL version `RestSharp` but get the same results -- `POST` succeeds and `GET` fails.

**Edit:**

This looks like it also may only be a problem when deployed to Azure, it works fine locally.

Comment: How is the server side method configured?

Comment: This is set up (in the `SponsorsController` like this: `[HttpGet]
public bool Get(string attendeeId, string sponsorId) [...] `).  Other than the controllers and whatnot, the WebAPI project is totally unaltered.